# Compare Dates Stored as String using Datetime

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have stored dates' date as `String` in my database in the following format :

```
 dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Now i need to access data between the two dates `startWeekDate` and `endWeekDate` both formatted as above. Currently , the **`where clause`** of my query is :

```
at_date BETWEEN Datetime( '"+startWeekDate+"') AND Datetime( '"+endWeekDate+"')
```

Where startWeekDate is `'10 Aug 2014'` and endWeekDate is `'16 Aug 2014'`. But I am getting the null result on my `TextView`. Can any one guide me how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Just use `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Well in that case, i need to change the whole database where i am inserting these dates...isn't there any other way to compare...:( ???